# SAS Convert string storing date as DDMonYY (date7.) to SAS Date

Tags: date, sas

I have dataset with dates stored as strings in a format ddMonyy e.g. 19Dec16.

When converting the strings using date7. informat to SAS date, some years are interpreted as 19yy and some as 20yy.

Here is a sample code

```
data strDates;
infile cards;
input StringDate $;
cards;
31Dec99
01Jan00
19Dec16
31Dec25
01Jan26
;
run;
data convertTest;
set strDates;
format Date date9.;
Date=input(StringDate,date7.);
run;
```

Running the code today (19 Dec 2016) produces the following results

```
strDate  date
31Dec99  31DEC1999
01Jan00  01JAN2000
19Dec16  19DEC2016
31Dec25  31DEC2025
01jan26  01JAN1926
```

Dates between 01Jan00 and 31Dec25  are assigned to years 2000-2025 while dates from 01Jan26-31Dec99 are treated as years 1926-1999

**Question:**

How is it determined if 2000 or 1900 is to added to the year? I suspect it is dependent on the runtime (calendar year when the code is run?) - but I was not able to find any reference to this in SAS documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an option, [YEARCUTOFF](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lesysoptsref/69799/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n0yt2tjgsd5dpzn16wk1m3thcd3c.htm), which depending on your system and version probably has a value of either 20 or 26.  See [KB note 46368](http://support.sas.com/kb/46/368.html) for more information on the change.

It sounds like you're using SAS 9.4, which means the default is 26: anything from 0-25 will be '20xx' and anything from 26-99 will be '19xx'.  You can change the `YEARCUTOFF` option if that value does not work for your data (or, construct the 4 digit year yourself).

Comment: Thank you @Joe that is exactly what I was looking for